# Cycling through two arrays and matching elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around an array matching problem in JavaScript.

I have two arrays:

```
array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
array2 = ["t", "u", "v", "w", "x"];
```

What I want to achieve is a cycle that works through each array and returns an array of objects that represent matched groups following the pattern:

```
1 to 1
1 to 1,2
1,2 to 1
1,2 to 1,2
1,2,3 to 1
1,2,3 to 1,2
1,2,3,4 to 1
1,2,3,4 to 1,2
```

Then once the cycle is over step up to the second character and carry on through. So for the above two arrays the result would be:

```
result = [
{1_1: "a;t", 1_12: "a;tu", 12_1: "ab;t", 12_12: "ab;tu", 123_1: "abc;t", 123_12: "abc;tu", 1234_1: "abcd;t", 1234_12: "abcd;tu"},
{1_1: "b;u", 1_12: "b;uv", 12_1: "bc;u", 12_12: "bc;uv", 123_1: "bcd;u", 123_12: "bcd;uv", 1234_1: "bcde;u", 1234_12: "bcde;uv"},
...and so on
];
```

The arrays don't have a major limit, but they will most likely be in the 5 to 12 characters long region although the outer limits in length are as short as 1 and as long as 30. If the array is is shorter than 4 then it stops when it gets to the end of the process it can. So for example:

```
array1 = ["a"];
array2 = ["b"];
result = [{1_1: "a;b"}];
```

I am assuming there is a fun game of recursion buried in this, but I don't even know how to approach this problem let alone word it in a way to make my google searches effective. Any help you could offer regarding getting started would be very appreciated.

Edit in response to comment:
What I'm looking for specifically is terms I can search to help me get started or pseudo code that would help me start the process of tackling this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hey ashcanschool, this is a well formed question. However their is no attempt from your side and a specific point where you got stuck. You probably get a full solution here but I would advise to include your attempt. People could correct your mistake and you will learn more from this than just a given solution.

Comment: My mistake is not knowing how to even approach it. I don't have attempts as I'm not sure how to begin. This is exacerbated by me not knowing terms of anything that is close to this type of action. However, you're right I most likely don't need a solution, but pseudo code would give me a brilliant leg up. If anyone has seen this type of mechanic before. I take your point that this could be looked at as begging for the answer. I'll attempt to address that in future questions.

Comment: The most important term you search for is "Permutations". I would advise reading this : https://medium.com/@swotboy2000/generating-permutations-from-n-arrays-3cd432f15c8b

Comment: Cheers, I'll give it a read.

Answer (score 0):

Alas Permutations came too late for me. Although it looks like I kind of went in that direction. I struggled with this until I gave up and just decided to essentially brute force an answer and this is what I came up with.

I am absolutely certain that this can be drastically simplified, but on this day I didn't have the mental capacity to get there. Sometimes you just have to force it. This is what I came up with:

```
const matchArrays = (array1: string[], array2: string[]): string[] => {

  let a1List: string[] = [];
  let resultList: string[] = [];
  let count: number = 4;
  (array1.length < 4) && (count = array1.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    a1List.push(array1[i]);
    array1[i + 1] !== undefined && a1List.push(array1[i] + array1[i + 1]);
    array1[i + 2] !== undefined && a1List.push(array1[i] + array1[i + 1] + array1[i + 2]);
    array1[i + 3] !== undefined && a1List.push(array1[i] + array1[i + 1] + array1[i + 2] + array1[i + 3]);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < a1List.length; i++) {
    resultList.push(a1List[i] + ";" + array2[Math.floor(i / count)]);
    resultList.push(a1List[i] + ";" + array2[Math.floor(i / count)] + array2[Math.floor(i / count) + 1]);
  }

  return resultList;
};
```

Thanks to anyone who stopped to read this.